# C++ Find Text & Count Occurrences

Tags: c++, find

I am doing some classwork and not having any luck getting my find to work appropriately.  When I run the code using CLION the code works appropriately for single words.  Multiple words do not work.  Also when uploading to the class website that tests it - the class website is not finding that the single words work.

Objective:  Implement the FindText() function, which has two strings as parameters. The first parameter is the text to be found in the user provided sample text, and the second parameter is the user provided sample text. The function returns the number of instances a word or phrase is found in the string. In the PrintMenu() function, prompt the user for a word or phrase to be found and then call FindText() in the PrintMenu() function. Before the prompt, call cin.ignore() to allow the user to input a new string.

My coding attempt:
    This first piece is within the menu and calls upon "FindText"

```
cout << "Enter a word or phrase to be found:" << endl;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, wordPhrase);
cout << "\"" << wordPhrase << "\" instances: " << FindText(userStr, wordPhrase) << endl << endl;
```

This is the code for "FindText"

```
int FindText(string userStr, string wordPhrase) {
    int numWords = 0;
    stringstream ss(userStr);

    while (ss >> userStr) {
        if (userStr == wordPhrase) {
            numWords++;
        }
    }

    return numWords;
}
```

Hopefully something simple that I am just missing :-\    Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `std::string` has a `find` method that might help with your probelm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another variable to hold the string you're reading from `ss`, rather than overwriting the string used for the `stringstream`.

```
int FindText(string userStr, string wordPhrase) {
    int numWords = 0;
    stringstream ss(useStr);
    string word;

    while (ss >> word) {
        if (word == wordPhrase) {
            numWords++;
        }
    }
    return numWords;
}
```